# IE9 - spinner not displaying during ajax request [resolved - don't use Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0]

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer-9

My code is as follows:

```
  function loadContent() {

    if(loading) { return false; }
    showSpinner();

    var xhr = createXHR();
    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/testing.php");
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if(xhr.readyState == 4) {
        hideSpinner();
        var resp = xhr.responseText;
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = resp;
      }
    }
    xhr.send(null);

  }

  function showSpinner() {
    document.getElementById("loadingIcon").style.display = 'inline';
    loading = true;
  }

  function hideSpinner() {
    document.getElementById("loadingIcon").style.display = 'none';
    loading = false;
  }
```

This works as intended in Firefox and Chrome, but in IE9 the spinner does not display.

I commented out the first line of the hideSpinner() function and found that IE9 does display the spinner, but only after the AJAX request has returned a result.
Have I done something out of order here?

[edit] Figured it out-- original code of createXHR() method follows:

```
  function createXHR() {
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0"); } catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0"); } catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP.3.0"); } catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
    try { return new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
    try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
    return null;
  }
```

Moving the last 'try' line to the top fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do not rely on global variables for such a thing. You do not need a `loading` variable at all.

```
function loadContent() {
  var spinner = document.getElementById("loadingIcon");
  var xhr = createXHR();

  spinner.style.display = 'inline';

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
      if (xhr.status == 200) {
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
      }
      spinner.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost/testing.php");
  xhr.send(null);
}
```

Comment: Hmm... the intent of the `loading` variable is to prevent more than one request from being fired, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Also, I changed the code as you suggested, still observed the same behavior in IE9, as described in top post

Comment: @joshivir: Ah, I see the use of the variable. Is there any error message in IE? Also, have you tried `"block"` instead of `"inline"`? In other words, does the spinner show at all if you issue the "style" command separately?

Comment: Didn't find any script errors in the IE console. Using `"block"` causes the spinner to be displayed in the wrong place :-) Not sure what you mean by the last question though...

Comment: Figured it out-- seems I was using a deprecated method of creating the AJAX request, editing top post with details. Thanks very much for your time :-)

Comment: @joshivir: So the XMLHTTP request itself wasn't even working? Or was it and just the spinner did not show? Because that would be a very strange thing…

Comment: The request itself was working fine, but IE was apparently waiting for the response to be returned before applying the style change.

Comment: I was able to narrow the problem down to `Msxml2.XMLHTTP.4.0` specifically... the `Msxml2.XMLHTTP.5.0` one failed to create an object, and all the other versions displayed the spinner as intended.